# Deleting elements of a list based on specific character

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list :

```
l={{a, b, d}, {a, v}, {b, c, d}}
```

I want to delete those elements that contain the letter a such that I get:

```
Output: {{b, c, d}}
```

I tried `DeleteCases` command but it does not work. What I we want two letters such as "a" and "c" In that case the output shall be empty. 
How one handles this?

Comment: Also consider `Select[l, FreeQ[a]]` and 
`Select[l, FreeQ[#, c] && MemberQ[#, v] &]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pick[l, FreeQ[a]  /@ l]
```

> {{b, c, d}}

Comment: Thanks, what if you want do to it for two letters like a and b? (in this case we expect an empty list). In other words can FreeQ be over two letters instead of only one?

Comment: @William Replace `a` by `a|b`

Comment: Fabulous thanks